# Grails: URL parameter in url mappings not interpreted as expected

Tags: grails

I'm writing a REST API with grails and need to put a variable on the path of a method.  The URL to call this method (which is delete) will look like:

http://localhost:8080/profiles/576/gameLibrary/591

I have the following in my URLMappings class:

```
        "/gameLibrary/${inventoryId}/"(controller: "profile", action: "removeFromLibrary", method: "DELETE")
```

I tried variations for the mapping like "$inventory" without the curly brackets and leaving off the trailing slash.  When I attempt to call this URL, I get a 404.  I've created the URL report, and I see the following for the mapping in question:

Controller: profile

|  DELETE  | /profiles/${profileId}/gameLibrary/null           | Action: removeFromLibrary           |

So, it's like it's trying to interpolate "${inventoryId} instead of using it as a path variable.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to create path variables.  I thought this section of the documentation on embedded variables was describing the approach I took:  http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#embeddedVariables.

Just in case it helps, posting my whole UrlMappings class:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/games"(resources:"game")
        "/gameGenres"(resources:"gameGenre")
        "/siteUsers"(resources:"siteUser")
        "/profiles"(resources:"profile") {
            "/gameLibrary" (controller: "profile", action: "getGameLibrary", method: "GET")
            "/gameLibrary" (controller: "profile", action: "addGameToLibrary", method: "PUT")
            "/gameLibrary/${inventoryId}/"(controller: "profile", action: "removeFromLibrary", method: "DELETE")
            "/wishList" (controller: "profile", action: "getWishList", method: "GET")
        }
        "/inventoryItems"(resources:"inventoryItem")

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Try it without the braces (`"/gameLibrary/$inventoryId/"...`); the syntax makes it look like it's a Groovy DSL and but it's actually parsed more mechanically using regex

Comment: Thanks Burt.  I should have mentioned that I already tried that variation.  I also tried without the trailing "/".

Comment: I found a way to make it work.  Apparently I didn't want this mapping under `"/profiles"(resources:"profile") {}` in the closure like I had it.  Instead, I moved it out to the top level:

`"/profiles/$profileId/gameLibrary/$inventoryId"(controller: "profile", action: "removeFromLibrary", method: "DELETE")`

This works just fine.